# Remove duplicates from array using Set, keeping highest id

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6

I have this array:

```
array = [{id: 1, name: 'apple'}, {id: 2, name: 'banana'}, {id: 3, name: 
'apple'}]
```

i need to remove objects with duplicated property "name" and i need to keep the highest id for remaining objects, like this:

```
newarray = [ {id: 2, name: 'banana'}, {id: 3, name: apple}]
```

i have tried this way:

```
array = [{id: 1, name: 'apple'}, {id: 2, name: 'banana'}, {id: 3, name: 
apple}]

newarray = Array.from(new Set(array.map(x => x.id)))
                 .map(id => {
                   return {
                     id: id,
                     name: array.find( s => s.id === id).name
})
```

result i get

```
newarray = [ {id: 2, name: 'banana'}, {id: 1, name: apple}]
```

i get the duplicated objects removed however i don't get the highest id for every remaining object.

thanks for give me an idea to get it.

Comment: Are the `id`s in order in the original array, as in the example?

Comment: This seems like a ridiculous way to get the job done. Why not just remove duplicates then do a reverse sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `reduce` instead - reduce into an object indexed by name, whose values are the associated `id` / `name` objects. If an object already exists at a given name, only reassign if the new object's ID is higher:

```js
const array = [{id: 1, name: 'apple'}, {id: 2, name: 'banana'}, {id: 3, name: 
'apple'}];

const newArray = Object.values(
  array.reduce((a, item) => {
    const { name } = item;
    if (!a[name] || a[name].id < item.id) {
      a[name] = item;
    }
    return a;
  }, {})
);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: You could do this too to simplify it `array.reduce((a, { name, id } => {`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I thought about that, but I wasn't entirely sure if OP wants to keep a reference to the original objects, or just needs the data in each

Comment: actually you would need this `(a, {name, id}, idx, orig)` and `a[name] = orig[idx];` either way works

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use a combination of map, filter, and reduce :)

Explanation in the code comments.

**See demo below**

```js
var array = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'apple'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'banana'
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'banana'
}, {
  id: -9,
  name: 'pear'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'apple'
}, {
  id: -3,
  name: 'pear'
}];

/*
  1 - it creates a Set from mapping original array into a list of names
  2 - it then maps it back into the objects but this time 
     2.1 - it filters the original array to elements with only matching names
     2.2 - and then it reduces the id to the highest value
*/
var filteredArray = Array.from(new Set(array.map(x => x.name))).map(e => {
  return {
    id: array.filter(function(el){
      return el.name == e;
    }).reduce((curr, next) => curr.id > next.id ? curr.id : next.id, 0),
    name: e
  }
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` and `reduce` to achieve the desired result as well

```js
Object.prototype.use = function(fn) {
  return fn(this)
}

var res = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'apple'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'banana'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'apple'
  }]
  .sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
  .reduce((o, d) => o[d.name] ? o : ({ ...o, [d.name]: d }), {})
  .use(r => Object.values(r))

console.log(res)
```